# Amazing sudoku who can find hot numbers

Tags: logical-deduction, sudoku

## Sudoku X

Place the numbers 1-6 once in every row, column, diagonal, and 3x2 block.  The diagonals form an X and are highlighted.

## Puzzle

[image: Wiut.uz]

## Text of puzzle

```
-----------------
| . . . | 5 . . |
| . . . | . . . |
-----------------
| 1 . . | 4 . . |
| . . 3 | . . . |
-----------------
| . . . | . . . |
| . . . | . . 6 |
-----------------
```

Can you solve it?

Comment: what exactly is the question??

Comment: You should find different numbers which aren't the same vertically , horizontally and in the figure of x (edge to edge)

Comment: Update the question to state the purpose.  Are you looking for help, or are you just posting this puzzle to solve?

Comment: It is so first time i am using this programm

Comment: What is the significance of the extra white square that is not part of the X?

Comment: It is not a amazing nor challenging.

Comment: Ok solve this if it isn't

Comment: Shaped like x figure is also main rule of sudoku

Comment: @JonathanAllan this is hint : left side of 3 and right side of 1  should be black

Comment: @user22143 Welcome to Puzzling.SE!  You need to slow down. :) When posting a puzzle it is important to note all of the details required as well as what the objective is.  You did not do that.  If you look at my edits to your post you can see what a well formatted post is.  Secondly, don't be offended by comments and get argumentative.  The people posting the comments genuinely want to solve your problem and are frustrated because they don't have enough information.  Good luck, and again, welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

> ```
> -----------------
> | 4 1 6 | 5 3 2 |
> | 2 3 5 | 6 1 4 |
> -----------------
> | 1 5 2 | 4 6 3 |
> | 6 4 3 | 1 2 5 |
> -----------------
> | 3 6 4 | 2 5 1 |
> | 5 2 1 | 3 4 6 |
> -----------------
> ```

Comment: Oh, didn't see the answer, weird.

Comment: @JonathanAllan At least we got the same answer :)

Comment: Verified, only solution :)

Answer (score 4):

I find that the solution is:

> ```
> +-------+-------+
> | 4 1 6 | 5 3 2 |
> | 2 3 5 | 6 1 4 |
> +-------+-------+
> | 1 5 2 | 4 6 3 |
> | 6 4 3 | 1 2 5 |
> +-------+-------+
> | 3 6 4 | 2 5 1 |
> | 5 2 1 | 3 4 6 |
> +-------+-------+
> ```

I have also written some Python code to check and found that it is indeed the only solution:

```
def initBoard():
    return [[0,0,0,5,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,4,0,0], [0,0,3,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,6]]

def solveBoard(board, r=0, c=0):
    if r==5 and c==5:
        for solution in genNext(board, r, c):
            yield solution
    else:
        if c == 5:
            nr = r+1
            nc = 0
        else:
            nr = r
            nc = c + 1
        for nextBoard in genNext(board, r, c):
            for solution in solveBoard(nextBoard, nr, nc):
                yield solution

def genNext(board, r, c):
    if board[r][c]:
        yield board
    else:
        for i in range(1,7):
            newBoard = [[i if ci==c else v for ci, v in enumerate(row)] if ri==r else list(row) for ri, row in enumerate(board)]
            if isValid(newBoard):
                yield newBoard

def isValid(board):
    s = set()
    for row in board:
        for v in row:
            if v:
                if v in s:
                    return False
                s.add(v)
        s.clear()
    for c in range(6):
        for row in board:
            v = row[c]
            if v:
                if v in s:
                    return False
                s.add(v)
        s.clear()
    for r in range(6):
        v = board[r][5-r]
        if v:
            if v in s:
                return False
            s.add(v)
    s.clear()
    for r in range(6):
        v = board[r][r]
        if v:
            if v in s:
                return False
            s.add(v)
    s.clear()
    for br in range(0,6,2):
        for bc in range(0,6,3):
            for r in (br, br+1):
                for c in (bc, bc+1, bc+2):
                    v = board[r][c]
                    if v:
                        if v in s:
                            return False
                        s.add(v)
            s.clear()
    return True

def printBoard(board):
    print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(v) for v in row) for row in board) + '\n')
```

Running it like so:

```
>>> for sln in solveBoard(b):
...     printBoard(sln)
```

Comment: I didn't know that we can solve it with the aid of programming

Comment: Yes, the program is just pure brute force, but works very quickly!

Comment: @JonathanAllan +1 for that code